# Unable to download artifact from private network nexus repo

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, nexus

I am trying to download the **artifacts from Nexus repo which is in private network** and i wanted to setup proxy and download these artifacts, but not sure how to setup the proxy.

Anyone suggest me how to download artifacts from Nexus repo which is in private network, also want to know is their any Groovy scripts to download these artifcats from Jenkins pipeline.

And Nexus repo which is in private network is using SSO authentication.

Thanks,

Comment: "i wanted to setup proxy and download these artifacts" - Do you want to setup a proxy, or are you trying to get through an existing proxy?  If the former, the question is too broad.  If the latter, are you using `@Grab`, Gradle, Maven, or something else to express dependencies?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown - I am planning to use new proxy because the Nexus is in private network, i dont have any plans using Gradle, Maven, or something else to express dependencies, because we have already built the .war/.jar file as part of the continous integration.

So the plan is to download the artificat from private Nexus and deployed it to the specific location.

Comment: " I am planning to use new proxy because the Nexus is in private network, i dont have any plans using Gradle, Maven, or something else to express dependencies, because we have already built the .war/.jar file as part of the continous integration" - Does your proxy require you to provide credentials to send requests through it?

Comment: I am not sure because still i havent set any proxy, I need the details how to set the proxy and use it.